# Como estipular detalhes com um SELECT

Tags: php, html

Bom, eu dei um SELECT, para puxar meus dados, só que eu queria fazer o seguinte:
Se $categoria for 1, ele se chamaria Mundo, e se $categoria fosse igual a 2, ele se chamaria Lua, como posso fazer isso?

**Código:**

```
    <?php
$conect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**Puxando o SELECT:**

```
<?php echo $conect['categoria']; ?>
```

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você quer, você quer imprimir com o `echo` "Mundo" ou "Lua"?

Comment: Doug clique em [editar logo abaixo da sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/76368/edit) e adicione mais detalhes do que você deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o comando `if`:

```
<?php 

if ($conect['categoria'] == 1){
  echo "Mundo";
}else if($conect['categoria'] == 2){
  echo "Lua";
}else{
  echo "Outros";
}; 

?>
```

Usando o comando `case`:

```
<?php 

switch ($conect['categoria']) {
  case 1:
    echo "Mundo"; break;
  case 2: 
    echo "Lua"; break;
  default:
    echo "Outros";
}

?>
```

Comment: Era isso que eu queria, obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você faz a consulta:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
$selectbase = mysql_select_db("base", $connection );
$slectdados = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error());

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($slectdados){
     if( $linha['categoria'] == "Mundo" ){
          echo "Mundo<br>";
     } elseif ( $linha['categoria'] == "Lua" ){
          echo "Lua<br>";
     } else {
          echo "Outros<br>";
}
```

Pode ser que dentro de um loop aonde seleciona todos os resultados você consiga assim ir imprimindo linha por linha conforme o valor de cada registro mas a pergunta é bem vaga.